# Running php file through command line?

Tags: php, file, command-line

Everytime I try to load a file through command line I get this message:

```
Could not open input file:  dummy.php
```

I have tried everything,

```
php C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\dummpy.php
php dummy.php
php htdocs\dummy.php
```

I can't run a file! I can get php information and all other stuff, so I belive my CLI is ok.

I actually need this to run phpwebsocket, but I can't run anything through CLI.

Comment: Either go into that directory or quote the full path because there is a space in it. Or use the old trustworthy `progra~2` instead

Comment: sorry, not sure i understood

Comment: What part is not clear?

Comment: i understood that i cannot run it because of the spaces in the directory, is that right? Excuse my poor english

Comment: When you open a command prompt, and you are entering these commands... what does the path show in the command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to enter the path without spaces, like this:

```
php c:\progra~2\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\dummy.php
```

Or, you can put quotes around the whole thing since your path does have spaces, like this:

```
php "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\dummy.php"
```

Or, when you open your command prompt, make sure to navigate to the folder that your PHP file exists in.   For example, a simple navigation might look this this (type enter after each line):

```
cd \
cd Program Files (x86)
cd zend
cd apache2
cd htdocs
php dummy.php
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your post, i am sure i am making progress. I do it as you said, and i got different messages, now it shows:
Successfully established connection to the database
Event reporting  is not allowed at the moment. Reasons: Pre Startup or Post Shutdown

This means that the file ran ok?

Comment: It sure sounds as if the file ran...  I'm not sure what the expected output is, but your comment does seem to indicate that the php file ran "successfully" and generated some type of output.

Comment: Yes, i created a simples hello world script and it ran ok, showed the result on the CLI, perfect! Thank you so much! Right and best answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
php dummy.php
```

you must be sure that your current directory is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\
```

Comment: could you explain how do i do that?